# Using ml model output to choose another ml model input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, boosting, anomaly-detection, stacking

I'm dealing with a low event rate problem (e.g. credit card fraud). 
I've balanced my data with SMOTE, and ran a neural net model (cross validated with recall as the measure).

However my precision (as can be expected) is very low.

I want to use the positive predictions (TP + FP) from my model as an input to another model - a subset of the original data. Creating a sort of "pipeline". 
Practically speaking, If a credit card company were to use my model, all the positive predictions will be handled by a human who would than decide whether or not it's a fraud, so why not automate?

Just like model stacking, but the stacked model gets a subset of the data and not the previous models predictions.

I'm not sure if that's OK. Any thoughts?

Comment: So you're saying you want to have your base model (neural net), and you feed ONLY the positive predictions to a next classifier (person/machine)?

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is called "Cascading classification" (feeding only certain rows of data to 2nd level classifier, based on what the first model said).

Answer (score 0):

stacking, is exactly use the prediction of previous models. You can find the ensemble method in the following book:

Z.-H. Zhou. Ensemble Methods: Foundations and Algorithms, Boca Raton, FL: Chapman & Hall/CRC, 2012. (ISBN 978-1-439-830031)

I think you method, just use the TP and FP not very well, except the recall metrics is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

If it works, why not? Define your objective and run the model on historical data to predict future. If predictive performance metrics show satisfying results, your method is good!
You're not using future unobserved data to predict future. Also you're not performing stats like pvalues to need any assumptions to hold. so your method is legit.

Note to use probability models not just classification models such as SVM since your outcome of interest is not common! You can determine probbility of fraud, can't detect it. The signal to noise ratio in your problem is very low, in which case classification methods usually fail badly!